# Google Oauth redirect to ios custom url

Tags: ios, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Goal: Complete Oauth2 from google in an iOS application.

I am using phonegap so I am launching the oauth in the browser.  I want the redirect to be a custom url for my app so I can store the token.  I have read [this post](https://plus.google.com/111487187212167051233/posts/AztHNnQh7w6) on how to handle redirect but am still confused.  What is the custom url that I should enter in my info.plist?  What redirect to I pass to the oauth page?

```
var redirect_url='com.example.myapp:/oauth2Callback'
var url="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=" + client_id + "&state=" + state + "&redirect_uri="+redirect_url+"&scope=" + scope;
```

Anyone experienced with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the above code is correct.  My issue was with setting the custom url scheme in my info.plist.  The url scheme needs to be the bundle id only(i.e.  com.example.myexample).  I had the ':/oauth2callback' appended to the end of it, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either the iOS bundle id or the Google issued client id to form the custom scheme based redirect URI. The post you link to gives a couple of examples.

Do you have an Apple issued bundle id for your app? If not, did you register with the Google developer console (that gives you a client id)?